# Get/Set "File History" (Windows 8) settings using C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, windows-8

I'm creating an app that suppose to run on windows 8 (Desktop)

I need to:

1. Enable users to launch "File History" using my app. I need to find the command line that opens "File History".
2. I need to be able to display the current settings of "File History".

I found that the data is saved under "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration.

The info is saved in an xml file. I prefer not to parse XML file especially if there is no specification of the exact format. So I wanted to know if there is another place where I can get the "File History" setting information from.

another thing is that for some reason I have there 2 files: config1 and config2. What is the difference between the files? which file contains the more accurate info?

Comment: Why do you use .NET 3.5 in Windows 8? If you're developing an app for upcoming OS use at most recent version as you can. I strongly recommend to use 4.5! There is no reason to avoid that, you have no legacy, etc. Also newer version will bring you more features, sometime you will suffer from a lack of the features you need.

Comment: I an aware of that. but I cannot use .net 4.5... Thanks for the advice anyway!

Comment: I depend on an old version of the software... the app should work on both win7 and win8.. I would have been more than happy to switch to .net 4.0 or above, but I just can't...

Comment: Don't forget that .Net 3.5 is *not* included with Windows 8, it requires a user download.  I suggest that you either don't target a specific CLR version or that you target .Net 4.0.

Comment: That is not correct. you should enable .net 3.5 on the platform and it works just fine.

Comment: Larry is a member of the Windows team at MS, I'd trust that he knows what he is talking about. Also, enabling .net 3.5 triggers a download to enable that feature.

Answer (score 3):

I found how to open the "File History" using C#.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = 
       new ProcessStartInfo("Control.exe",@"/name Microsoft.FileHistory");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

and if you want to get to the "Restore personal files" navigation item, you should launch:

> "C:\Windows\System32\FileHistory.exe"