# File History on windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-8

I have a question related to [Get/Set “File History” (Windows 8) settings using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160999/get-set-file-history-windows-8-settings-using-c-sharp)

Windows has provided an API [File History API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that *"allows applications to read and modify the File History configuration"*

1. Is there a C# version of this API?
2. Does it require .NET 4.5?
3. Are there any code samples of how to use this API?

Answer (score 2):

I found a cpp sample that demonstrate how to use File History

[File history Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/FileHistory-e1d403aa)

this works well :)

I just need to find a way to move it from cpp to c#

Comment: I tried to find where the com object is located, so I can create a wrapper using tlbimp.exe, but I coudn't find it.