# Programmatically add a folder to Windows File History

Tags: windows, winapi, backup

How can I programmatically add a folder to the File History backup system?

Other questions like [File History on windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892105/file-history-on-windows-8) mention a Microsoft code sample for File History, but the link has gone dead.

Comment: The sample  wouldn't help you because  it is about starting and stopping the service. The service backs up your libraries, so if you want to add a folder, add it to a library.

Comment: @RaymondChen: This may be a dumb question (I'm no Windows expert), but can you "add it to a library" without actually moving the folder?  Maybe put a shortcut in a library?

Comment: The #1 web search hit for `add folder to library` says as its first two sentences "[A library gathers content from various folders. You can include folders from different locations in the same library](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Include-folders-in-a-library)."