# File History in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, file, backup, windows-8.1-universal, file-recovery

I know this question has been apparently asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167855/how-file-history-works-in-windows-8-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892105/file-history-on-windows-8)

But mine is different.

1. Do file histories include only extensions such as pdf, jpg, mp3, doc
   etc

   2. File history for moved files is available not just deleted ones?
   3. At preset I am accessing C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent folder
      But here I am not able to see recently modified files which come under a directory in Users\Myname folder. Why do all recent files not get mentioned here?

Is there place where these settings can be changed?

4. Is it possible to look up recently accessed/modified folders?

I have a developing background in assembly and C but restarting after more than 6 years. I saw other threads where they were doing things programmatically but did not understand much and looked their requirements were different from mine. I am willing to try out programmatic solutions if an online source is pointed to.

I take a regular back up of my files, but yesterday happened to give my PC into someone's hand when learning something and the person was an impulsive shift deleter not even bothering with the messages on the PC and was not very aware of what was being done or happening.

Question 2 is because I have earlier accidentally moved folders into another folder in a previous PC

Comment: Recent Files keeps track of files that have been *opened*, not files that have been moved or deleted.

Comment: Why am I not able see recently modified files which I do through Android studio?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details.  But there's nothing forcing an application to tell Explorer about files that are opened and/or modified.  Presumably Android Studio doesn't.

Comment: Okay, thanks. 

"there's nothing forcing an application to tell Explorer about files that are opened and/or modified" was useful to me. 

In my previous laptop with Windows Vista I had noticed that mp3 files were not showing in the recent history. In my current laptop I have Power media player. When music tracks are played with this they show in history but not when played with Windows Media player

As for Android studio, when we want apk files to show in explorer we need to right clock on the file name in the studio and click on "Show in explore". I shall find out more about this thanks

Comment: @HarryJohnston I found something called Recent Places in Windows 8.1 and am able to see folders accessed because of using Android Studio. Here able to see recently modified files by clicking on that folders. This was not possible in Recent Items. Just thought of sharing this with you

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I was trying to help somebody else find a file they recently accessed

In Windows 8.1 there is something called "Recent Places" under Favorites in File Explorer. This was in the same favorite list where I had kept Recent Items and still did not notice it because of getting panicky. This showed me the folders I had accessed something I really wanted a week back. It would have saved me so much tension and my precious time.

Now am planning to update to Windows 10 and google searched if I will still have access to this data and found this
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/restore-recent-places-to-windows-10/037af727-9b06-485e-bb45-4a6c60a3f222?auth=1

Hope this is useful to someone